# Integral $I(a,b,c,s)=\int_s^\infty K_0(\sqrt{x^2+a})cos(b+cx)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions

I need help with integral:
$$I(a,b,c,s)=\int_s^\infty K_0(\sqrt{x^2+a})cos(b+cx)dx$$
where $K_0$ is the $0^{th}$ modified Bessel functions of the second kind.

Does this integral have a closed form? And if it does, can someone help me to find it?

Comment: Can you do $I(1,0,0,0)$?  If not, there is little hope for this more general integral.

Comment: It is known that $$I(a,0,c,0) = \frac{\pi }{{2\sqrt {1 + c^2 } }}\exp \left( { - \sqrt {a + ac^2 } } \right).$$

Comment: Thank you for answers! Unfortunately, in my case, variables `a,b,c,s` are the complex functions, that can't be equal $0$ or $1$.